# Can't identify venom/spiderman minifigures

Tags: set-identification, minifigures, clone-brands, minifigure-identification

I can't identify these Venom/Spiderman minifigures and I have no idea what set they're from but they are probably about 6-7 years old. I'm not sure if those are the right bottoms for Venom, but I know that the head and torso match (and one of Spiderman's hands are mismatched as well). Does anyone recognize these particular ones? Thanks for the help[image: ![matching spider and symbiote minifigures]

Comment: These torsos are from some kind of clone brand, not Lego

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think they come from this Megabloks set

[image]